# How Do I create notification in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-online, notifications, maintenance

I want to create a message alert to send to users information them off sharepoint being down for maintenance. we are using sharepoint online not on premise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe SharePoint online has any hooks into their Service Health for notifications other than the mobile app.

However, it appears if you're able to check the status codes returned from an http request to the site periodically, you could figure out whether the site was working.

This example is for powershell - see Jordan Mill's example: 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/955754db-e85b-4cf9-a516-eaec405706b9/how-to-check-the-availability-of-a-site-using-powershell

I'm guessing there are many ways to tackle this .. but I think they'd all be external and would involve you having a list of users you can send alerts to readily available (or a group).

As a side note, there do appear to be O365 monitoring tools but you could probably search for those on your own.